# Jenkins: Escaping Quotes when Executing a Bash/Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-cli

I'm having some trouble understanding how to pass a string which needs to contain spaces and quotes through a jenkins parameter to an execute shell command. Here is a simplified version:

**Wrapper Script On Jenkins Server**:

```
#!/bin/sh
str_line=$1

/home/user/aws-cli-wrapper blahblah wrapper-command $str_line
```

**Execute Shell Command**:

```
./wrapper-script $str_line
```

I am passing in `"aws ec2 describe-instances"` inside the jenkins parameter box (including the quotes) but the console output is printing out the following which causes the script not to work correctly, I believe.

```
'"aws' ec2 'describe-instances"'
```

Could anyone shed some light on how to properly pass the string through as one long string (if possible)?

I'll also need to be able to escape quotes too - such as:

```
"aws ec2 describe-instances --filters \"Name=instance-state-name,Values=running\" --query \"Reservations[].Instances[]\" --output json --region eu-west-1"`
```

But I thought maybe one baby step at a time :)

Sorry if this is an easy/stupid answer but I couldn't find post that answered my question.

Comment: How would `aws-cli-wrapper` be used directly on the command line, if you were typing the whole command from the wrapper instead of passing an argument? In general, you need to quote all your parameter expansions, but it's not clear to me if `aws-cli-wrapper` expects multiple arguments or just needs a single string that it will parse itself.

Comment: @chepner Yeah sure. So I'm not sure exactly what is happening within it as unfortunately I don't have access to it. 

However I know it isn't that script causing the issue because with my current execute shell command in my jenkins job: 

    `./wrapper-script $str_line`

If I substitute the variable to be the hardcoded string `"aws ec2 describe-instances"`, it works.

So it's something to do with the Jenkins Parameter passing it into the Execute Shell Command build action.

Comment: As currently written, that becomes `./wrapper-script aws ec2 describe-instances` after word-splitting. However, any quotes you try to embed in your argument will be treated as *literal* characters, not quotes to protect whitespace. For example, with the arugment `"aws 'foo bar'"`, the command becomes `./wrapper-script aws \'foo bar\'` (three arguments), not `./wrapper-script aws 'foo bar'` (two arguments).

Comment: Read [Bash FAQ 50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for some background on the problem you are facing.

Comment: @chepner ok cool, I'll have a read, thanks. Hardcoding the string (with double quotes) instead of parameterising it shows it as `./wrapper-script 'aws ec2 describe-instances'` in the console output (which works). If I try to run it from the jenkins parameter, it will evaluate it as `./wrapper-script aws ec2 describe-instances` (without quotes) which, as you said, will treat them as individual arguments. That's why I attempted to wrap the whole thing in quotes in the jenkins parameter input, but it caused the weird single quotes being generated.